# Trying to convert '2020-12-28' to only month, for example 'December'

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to convert '2020-12-28' to only month, for example 'December'.

I already converted the column to `datetime` from object and then used the following code:

```
df['month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['ArrivalDate']).month
```

But this code gives me the error

```
'Length of value does not match length of index'.
```

However, the column 'ArrivalDate' is not the index and I do not intend to make it either. I also have multiple values with the same dates and I want to aggregate them based on months.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) to convert datetime to string with format you designate.

```py
df['month'] = df['ArrivalDate'].dt.strftime('%B')
```